# How to scroll Item of Horizontal Scrollview inside of display when Click?

Tags: java, android, horizontalscrollview

I am trying to scroll item of horizontalView inside display of phone [like discreatescrollview](https://github.com/yarolegovich/DiscreteScrollView).

I am trying this

```
  private final void focusOnView(final HorizontalScrollView scroll, final View view) {

    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int vLeft = view.getLeft();
            int vRight = view.getRight();
            int sWidth = scroll.getWidth();
            scroll.smoothScrollTo(((vLeft + vRight - sWidth) / 2), 0);
        }
    });
}
```

But it scroll to center not it's child also.

I am trying to add button like this...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I prepare to use recycle-view in this case so I can add

1.snapHelper to snap the items 
2.add ItemAnimator and change it is easy 
3.adding new item in the future is just adding new object in the array 
4.scroll animation is very smooth